# How to write complex predicate for discovery locator in Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I want to customize discovery locator behavior. On of my cases is, for example, routing from `gateway_host/prohibitions` to service named `prohibitions-ui`. For this purpose I'm using this config:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
          filters: PreserveHostHeader
          include-expression: serviceId.endsWith('-UI')
          predicates: Path='/'+serviceId.substring(0,serviceId.indexOf('-UI'))+'/**'
```

Then error:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.predicates' to java.util.List<org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.predicate.PredicateDefinition>:

Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.predicate.PredicateDefinition
```

I think this error rising because of two arguments passed to `substring` method. If I change method call to `substring(0)` then application starts successfully, but such config for me doesn't make sense:
`predicates: Path='/'+serviceId.substring(0)+'/**'`

Answer (score 0):

The property `spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.predicates` refers to a list of predicate definitions, see `org.springframework.cloud.gateway.discovery.DiscoveryLocatorProperties`. What you specified is converted to a `String` and as such cannot be converted to the required type.

You may try to specify your predicates as follows:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          predicates: 
          - name: Path
            args:
              pattern: '/'+serviceId.substring(0,serviceId.indexOf('-UI'))+'/**'
```